# Page template showing categories and related articles

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a template that will show a taxonomy with the associated sub taxonomies and posts below it. The custom taxonomy is setup lik a category so the view would be something like this:

Definitions:
Custom Post Type = Appellation
Custom Taxonomy = Designation

Designation
-child of designation
*post in appellation categorized to designation
*post in appellation categorized to designation

Here is my [page template in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xEuCYasP)  for pulling this off, and it mostly works but I can't get the posts to show up under the designations. If I delete line 73 then I get every appellation post showing up under every designation... I'm guessing I'm just not grabbing the posts by designation properly but am stumped at this point...

Comment: For Line 32, is it meant to be the custom taxonomy? In which case it'd be `'custom_taxonomy' => 'term_slug'`

Comment: I hadn't actually realized line 32 was an issue until just a moment ago when I noted the links weren't right. I actually just changed that line to this and that part seems to be working right:`code` echo '<h2><a href="' . get_term_link($category->slug, $category->taxonomy) . '" title="' . $category->name . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></h2>';`code`

Comment: Ack, sorry I meant in 73..Not sure how I typed 32. Is that line meant to be calling the term from the custom taxonomy or a regular category?

Comment: You need to post that as an answer :)... I had tried  'designation' => $category -> term_id  among other things to no avail.... But lo  'designation' => $category -> slug yields the desired result! Now I can go play some x-box, guilt free :)

Comment: Hah. I ran into the same issue not too long ago. Realized custom taxonomies/terms needed to be called like that, you can't just give it a category ID because it's technically not a `category` persay. Glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to query a term from a custom taxonomy you need to alter your line 73

from `'category' => $category->term_id`

to `'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY'` => `'TERM_SLUG'`

replacing CUSTOM_TAXONOMY with the custom taxonomy name and TERM_SLUG with the term slug.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies